# Why are the contents of these pointers changing inside this Vector and throwing a read access violation exception?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Basically, I am finishing a game engine, and one of the processes is to evaluate collision detection between colliders.

The problem is, is that the gameObjects/colliders I collect from the game map seems to completely change after several iterations of searching for collision detections.

Below shows how I obtained these colliders, I give the game map an empty vector called mapObjects so that it fills the vector with game objects

```
Game.cpp

vector<SimObject*> mapObjects;
currentMap = new GameMap("GameMap.txt", mapObjects, *texManager);


renderer->SetScreenProperties(16, currentMap->GetMapWidth(), currentMap->GetMapHeight());

for (int i = 0; i < mapObjects.size(); i++) {

    AddNewObject(mapObjects[i]);
}
```

Then the map objects get processed through a function, which is put onto another vector and also dissected to place the collider and the rigid body into two other different vectors, allColliders and allBodies:

```
Game.cpp

    void Game::AddNewObject(SimObject* object) {
    newObjects.emplace_back(object);
    physics->AddRigidBody(object);
    if (object->GetCollider()) {
        physics->AddCollider(object->GetCollider());
    }
}
```

The way the game map obtains these objects is by evaluating the game map data, transforms these into Vector4 instances containing x, y, width and height, then is iterated and transformed into game objects for e.g. finding the walls:

```
GameMap.cpp

    for (int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++) {
    Wall* wall = new Wall(walls[i]);
    objects.emplace_back(wall);
}
```

Inside the wall constructor, this happens:

```
Wall::Wall(Vector4 vec) : StaticObject(vec)
```

which the following involves this basically:

```
StaticObject::StaticObject(Vector4 vec)
{
    float midX = vec.x + ((vec.z - vec.x) / 2.0f);
    float midY = vec.y + ((vec.w - vec.y) / 2.0f);
    SetPosition(Vector2(midX, midY));

    float halfW = midX - vec.x;
    float halfH = midY - vec.y;

    SetCollider(new CollisionVolume(this, Vector2(halfW, halfH)));
    fixed = true;
}
```

Everything works fine at first, but after several iterations of this:

```
Game.cpp

    void GameSimsPhysics::CollisionDetection(float dt) {

    for (int i = 0; i < allColliders.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < allColliders.size(); ++j) {
            allColliders[i]->DetectCollision(*allColliders[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

A read access violation is thrown:

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
> this was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I had an investigate through the debugger, and it says that it is unable to read memory of the contents. However, if game objects were added within Game.cpp just after finding the map objects, their contents seem to be still in tact and unchanged:

```
player = new PlayerCharacter();
player->SetPosition(Vector2(100, 32));
player->SetCollider(new CollisionVolume(player, 10.0f));
AddNewObject(player);
```

I am really unsure and stuck at the moment, so I will appreciate any help! I have tried to keep it as simple as possible, but let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: hard to say decisively without a [mcve], but I'm guessing vector reallocation

Comment: Probably internal storage of the std::vector relocating and making any stored pointers/references/iterators to the elements of the vector invalid. eg _"...If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back